# JSON string validation with Google's Gson?

Tags: java, json

I have to exposed a REST servivce, This service will take json string and then it will vaerify against the json schema, to check if input json string confirms the json schema. If input json string confirms the schmea then i have to create a asynch thread which will process the json data.

Please guide , how can i perform following:

1. Json string validation against json scheam using Google's Gson.
2. How can i create asynch thread which will be process my json request
   after the validation is successfull.

If the validation is not possible using Google's Gson, then what other logic i can use.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `try{...} catch{...}` structure around the parser. If the JSON string is invalid, it will throw a parse- or syntaxerror. It saves analyzing the string twice as well, so its easier in multiple ways. For creating an async thread, take a look at the `implements Runnable` examples in the java docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html. Another possibility would be to use the `FutureTask` class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html. It all depends on what you want to do with the result.

Comment: I do not want the parsing logic in my client class, i jsut want to validated the json string against the json schmea, if confirms then parsing logic would be in thread. please suggest.